# Undefined Behavior with v-for and custom components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, row, v-for

First off, please excuse the awful code (we don't have time to fix right now). I know `eval` is horrible, but for our purposes it was the only thing that worked for us this easily.

This is how we add and remove the rows:

```
methods: {
    addRow: function() {
        let lastRow = eval(`this.$parent.json${this.path}[this.$parent.json${this.path}.length - 1]`);
        lastRow = Object.assign({}, lastRow);
        eval(`this.$parent.json${this.path}.push(lastRow)`);
        this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    removeRow: function(index) {
        //eval(`this.$parent.json${this.path}.splice(index, 1)`);
        eval(`Vue.delete(this.$parent.json${this.path}, index)`);
        this.$forceUpdate();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00e58as4/10/6

To recreate the issue, add a row. Then, change the text on the new row. Try removing the second-to-last row - notice how it doesn't get deleted, but the last one is. However, if you check the json-debug which is a live view of the backend data, you'll see that the proper row gets deleted!

Why does this happen? Why are the UI and the backend not in sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always use a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) when iterating with `v-for`. Try adding one like this.

```
<div class = "well" v-for = "item, index in items" :key="item">
```